# Factory Resetting Windows 11 Computer and Then Switching Drives

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-11, storage

I built my computer, but ever since I added two drives, it has been acting up. I'd like to remove my old, 256GB drive (the current C) drive, and just switch my current D drive to the C drive to use as my default drive.

I know that after factory resetting your computer, some files are kept (if you desire so) and the rest are moved to `windows.old`.

The problem is that I'm worried that after factory resetting, my files that are kept, along with `windows.old` will be put on my current C drive, but I want them on my D drive.

Can anyone walk me through resolving this?

Thank you!

---

C Drive: 256GB <- *remove this*
D Drive: 2TB <- *keep this*

---

Comment: How do you intend on switching drives? Just copying/imaging over? Also, the windows.old folder is for upgrades, not resets. I think you should split your problem apart and solve each part individually. I don't think one conflicts with the other, and I think you may be assuming there will be complexities that will not be there.

Answer (score 2):

> but ever since I added two drives, it has been acting up

Not sure what that really means. How is it acting up? I highly doubt that "adding two drives" makes a computer to "act up".

Perhaps reconsider and investigate/troubleshoot the acting up on its own.

---

To get a clean Windows (factory reset, but even more than that...) I would say you should:

1. Create a bootable Windows Installation USB using the [media creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11)
2. Shut down the computer
3. Unplug the current C: (256GB) drive from the computer, and leave it unplugged
4. (Optional) connect the current D: (2TB) drive to the SATA port in the computer that the C: drive was connected. Basically, put the 2TB to the SATA port 0 on the motherboard
5. Boot the computer from the bootable windows install USB
6. Install Windows on the 2TB drive (delete all partitions in the installation wizard and start from a clean drive)
7. (Optional) If you want to have the 256GB drive as an additional drive for none system things, you can then plug it in and delete all partitions from it and create one big regular partition on it

*Note: Obviously this process will delete all files on the drives, so if you have data files you want to keep you should copy them first to a 3rd drive.*

Comment: What if I have important data on some apps or games, or I can't figure out where one or more file(s) are/is stored? Is there a way to do a backup to a cloud service/USB drive that automatically includes all data that isn't Windows data, or such?

Comment: There is no automatic way to know what is "not Windows data". The best option to be safe would be to do a full disk image, from which you will be able to pull out files if needed, and even put the image back to the disk to get your old system up and running.

Comment: The issue is that to back up my 1.5 TB of data, I would need to spend at least $100 on a USB drive, when only about 0.5 TB of that data is actually real data, and not Windows data and app data. Any ideas?

Comment: You can get 2 TB external hard drives for like $65, but I see where you're coming from. But unfortunately, there is no foolproof way to copy "all the potentially needed files". (BTW, if I understood correctly your Windows files are on the 256GB drive anyhow, so the 1.5 TB isn't that...)

Comment: I have two drives, and the data added up on both of them is roughly 1.5TB. Are there any good and cheap cloud backup alternatives?